# How to run multiple Azure Functions instances at the same time without loosing performances? (I/O bound tasks)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm working on a Azure Function (Queue Triggered) that can process a 1000 requests to an external API. I am doing this concurrently using `asyncio` and `aiohttp`. My goal is to process 100k requests (100k/1k = 100 AFs) and would like to run multiple Azure Functions at the same time so I can reduce the execution time.

When running just one AF everything works fine and the process is fast. When trying 2 concurrently it is slow down. But when trying to run more than 3, it gets insanely slow and would make more sense to just run everything sequentially. The function app is on Premium plan.

I have the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` application setting set to 10 (maximum). Using `asyncio` my code is running in a single thread, so I was under the impression that having more AF instance they would spread on the workers and not impact each other performances. Did I not understand the concept correctly?

Ultimately my question is what can I do on the Function app level to allow such scenarios?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The functions are running on separate instances, this should allow you to process 100 messages in parallel, without the CPU consumption of one instance affecting the others (depending on your hosting plan).

When the processing time increases as you add instances, then there is an indication that there is a locked resource that is blocking the other instances from processing messages, or a resource that cannot handle the load.

Since you are using aiohttp, could it be that the site that you are communicating with that has problems scaling?

Comment: I don't think the api I'm requesting is the problem as locally I can run batches concurently without having issue. I thought that it was more my function configuration that was wrong. I'm running on premium plan EP1.

Comment: How have you configured scale out? Is there a cap on the number of instances? The other problem you may have is cold start, you could test this by allocating 3 "Always Ready Instances"

Comment: I only had 1 ready instances, changed it to 3 after your comments but it doesn't seem to change anything. I'm having some trouble witht the CPU it seems, I get this warning from the function app logs:  `[Warning] [HostMonitor] Host CPU threshold exceeded (89 >= 80)`. I thought that running asynchronously in each instances would not affect the cpu usage